# Вопрос по xml коду (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-xml

Ниже код возбуждает предупреждение, что "XML tag has empty body"

```
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
```

а вот если просто поместить курсор мышки на место body и нажать на LClick, потом Enter, то полученный ниже новый вид кода

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </LinearLayout>
```

уже не выдает такого предупреждения.

Как это понимать? Ну в смысле, с чем связано такое странное поведение 
        среды разработки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это стандартная инспекций в AndroidStudio, её можно отключить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему она говорит, что проблемы нет, когда есть перенос строки или пробел? Все просто, xml тег содержит пустое тело только тогда, когда в нем нет ни одного пробела, то есть сразу после открывающего тега идет закрывающий. Если добавить хотя бы один пробел, то тело xml тега уже будет не пустым.

Comment: хD эххх, что что, но про пробел не учел (обидно стало, ну и ладно). Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Это стандартное предупреждение линта. В разметке по-хорошему не должно быть пусты тегов.

Т.е . код у Вас должен выглядеть не так:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
```

А, вот так:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Это предупреждение не из числа критичных, но лучше стараться делать валидную вёрстку.

Comment: Спасибо, что поделились этой тонкостью.